# Problem about a proof : Taylor-Young

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

motivate by the so-called inequality :
$$e^x\geq x+1$$
I was creating a new inequality like this :

Let $x\leq -8$ a real number so we have :
$$\frac{e^x-1}{x}\geq \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$$

My proof :

take the Taylor-Young formula we get :

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f(a)^{(k)}(x-a)^k}{k!}$$

But we have for all $x$ :
$$f(x)^{(k)}\leq \frac{1}{k+1}$$

So we get :

$$\frac{\sin(x)}{x}=f(x)\leq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{(x-a)^k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{1-e^{x-a}}{a-x}$$

And finally put $a=0$ to get the desired result

But I think there is a mistake.It would be cool if you could help me.

Thanks a lot for your contributions .

Comment: define $$f(x)=\sin(x)+1-e^x$$ and use calculus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is elementary . . .

When you replaced the factors $f^{(k)}(a)$ by ${\large{\frac{1}{k+1}}}$, those terms where the cofactor is negative will *decrease*.

Also, it's easy to see that for $x < 0$, the claimed inequality fails whenever 
$x \equiv {\large{\frac{3\pi}{2}}}\;(\text{mod}\;2\pi)$.

For example, given your specified domain $x \le -8$, the inequality fails for 
$x={\large{\frac{3\pi}{2}}} - 6\pi$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer (+1) what would you advise me to obtain a inequality wich works ?

Comment: I don't have a clear idea of the type of inequality you're trying for.